# Simple but serious issue with Tablet programming for android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So I'm taking the course by Google "Developing Android Apps" and I am stuck since I ran into a serious problem I can't explain:

See,their idea is to have a different layout file for tablets under the folder res\layout-sw600dp so that if the minimum height/width of the device is 600dips then there will be a different layout inflated.
The only problem is that for some reason that assertion doesn't work, not for their code nor for the simple code i added here,at least not for an AVD tablet (I've used Nexus 10 with api 21).
For example the following code shows "Phone!" on the toast rather than "Tablet!":

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String TABLET="Tablet!";
    static final String PHONE="Phone!";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String foundDeviceStr;

        if(findViewById(R.id.weather_detail_container)==null){
            foundDeviceStr=PHONE;

        } else{
            foundDeviceStr=TABLET;

        }

        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this,foundDeviceStr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();



    }
}
```

When the xml file under the folder layout-sw600dp does have a frame with the id weather_detail_container.

I will add both xml files that I created at the bottom of the email, but you can also try out branch 5.10 from the following Google project- it doesn't load a two panes as it should:
https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/tree/5.10_selected_item, again at least not for any AVD devices (I have a physical android phone but not a physical tablet).

For the question to be complete here are the two xml files:

under the folder layout this is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Whatever"/>

      </LinearLayout>
```

and under the folder layout-sw600dp this is activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity">

    <!--
    This layout is a two-pane layout for the Items master/detail flow.
    -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
       android:text="Whatever" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/weather_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle difference screen sizes so that a textview scales](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151761/how-to-handle-difference-screen-sizes-so-that-a-textview-scales)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys,so I just got a viable answer to my question:
Simply uncheck "enable device frame" in emulator settings!
If you need further assistance you can use this link:
[How to remove the device's frame on Android Studio's emulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766821/how-to-remove-the-devices-frame-on-android-studios-emulators)

Having said all that, I am not sure WHY that works. After all,the definition of this setting is:  "Enable a frame around the Android emulator window that mimics the look of a real android device", so that SHOULD change only the looks according to my understanding. So if anyone knows why, please do post a further answer or comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask/get the `SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK` that is the key...
I have tried **ONLY** on samsung devices but it was pretty accurate....

## Example:

```
Context myAppContext = ...//load the context here...;

boolean amATablet = (myAppContext.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
if (amATablet) {
    
    //Hello Tablet
}else{
    //hello Phone
}
```

Comment: Thanks BUT this still won't help inflate the correct layout file
(and if I have to inflate all of the views at runtime rather than use xml then that will break the decoupling between the code and the objects i want to use,right?)...On top of that,under getResources() you could get the width and height of the phone, and compare it to the constant 600- that would be a better way to do that manually which is NOT what i'm looking for!!